# Will we be reunited with our family and friends in heaven?

Tags: christian-living, faith, kingdom-of-god

Yes, I have faith in God and I would really like to go to heaven after I die, not hell, no way! I trust in God and would like to see my family and friends in heaven after they die, only if they make it there. I would never, ever want to go to hell!

Comment: the title seems to have a decent question if a bit broad, but the content doesn't seem to contain a question or further details. Is there a particular denomination you're asking about?

Comment: I was just saying I have faith in God and I would like to go to heaven after I die, not hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not directly addressed in Scripture, we can draw some ideas from Scripture.

> Revelation 7:17  For the Lamb which is in the midst of the throne shall feed them, and shall lead them unto living fountains of waters: and God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes.
>
> Rev_21:4  And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things are passed away.

Since there will be no ***tears, death, sorrow, crying or pain*** in Heaven. Does it not follow that not seeing those we loved here on Earth would only cause us sorrow.

> Revelation 20:6  Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years.
>
> Revelation 20:13 and 14  And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works. And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

Here we see that death is banished and will no longer be an inhibition, nor will it have any effect on those who are part of the first resurrection. the first resurrection is the resurrection of the faithful
and the second death refers to:

> Revelation 21:8  But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death.

These are those destined for Hell. Although these Scriptures do speak directly to missing any loved one who are not in Heaven, it makes it seem that we will not know that they are not there.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

> David noticed that his attendants were whispering among themselves,
>   and he realized the child was dead. “Is the child dead?” he asked.
>   “Yes,” they replied, “he is dead.” Then David got up from the ground.
>   After he had washed, put on lotions and changed his clothes, he went
>   into the house of the LORD and worshiped. Then he went to his own
>   house, and at his request they served him food, and he ate. His
>   attendants asked him, “Why are you acting this way? While the child
>   was alive, you fasted and wept, but now that the child is dead, you
>   get up and eat!” He answered, “While the child was still alive, I
>   fasted and wept. I thought, ‘Who knows? The LORD may be gracious to me
>   and let the child live.’ But now that he is dead, why should I go on
>   fasting? Can I bring him back again? **I will go to him, but he will
>   not return to me.**” (2 Samuel 12:19-23, NIV)

David was convinced that when he died, he would be reunited with his dead son. Our assurance is based on faith, not a detailed contract authored by God.

It is also interesting to note that Job was satisfied with God’s answer. That answer included giving him twice as many years as he already had lived, giving him twice as many cattle, and generally doubling everything - but not children. He only got ten more children, not twenty. Children cannot be replaced. Job believed that if he died, he would live again. That means that his children would, too, so he would one day be reunited with them. This is nowhere stated, but by Job’s response, we can see that was his faith.